# Writing Path properly to save a file

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm trying to save a transformed etl table to a CSV in a specific directory. I have the following method:

```
def save_transformed_data_to_csv(self, data, path):
    fund = data.values('FundCode')[0]
    # 'convert' transforms date strings into datetime objects 
    start_date = convert(data.values('PositionStartDate')[0], date)
    end_date = convert(data.values('PositionDate')[0], date)

    filename = 'citco_transformed_positions_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(fund=fund, start=start_date, end=end_date)     
    filepath = Path(path, filename)
    data.tocsv(filepath)
```

Printing out the formatted filename returns this:

`citco_transformed_positions_>PWPR1_2018-07-01_2018-07-11.csv`
And I'm calling it like this:

```
# Store transformed data for unmapping processing
loader.save_transformed_data_to_csv(transformed_data, '/Users/cgrijalva/Misc/UnmappedPositions')
```

And when running it, I get the following error:

`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\Users\\cgrijalva\\Misc\\UnmappedPositions\\citco_transformed_positions_>PWPR1_2018-07-01_2018-07-11.csv'`

Comment: You cannot have `>` in filenames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7496931/user7496931) pointed out, you can not have `>` in file name or path. one workaround is:

```
import re
fname = 'citco_transformed_positions_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(fund=fund, start=start_date, end=end_date)
fname = re.sub('[^\w\-_\. ]', '_', fname)
print(fname)
citco_transformed_positions__PWPR1_2018-07-01_2018-07-11.csv
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel stupid now ^_^. No other characters are allowed for filenames other than '-', '_', and alphanumeric values right?

Comment: We all are guilty of doing such things!